# When does pandas do pass-by-reference Vs pass-by-value when passing dataframe to a function?

Tags: pandas, numpy, pass-by-reference, immutability, deep-copy

```
def dropdf_copy(df):
    df = df.drop('y',axis=1)

def dropdf_inplace(df):
    df.drop('y',axis=1,inplace=True)    

def changecell(df):
    df['y'][0] = 99


x = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2],'y': [20,31]})

x
Out[204]: 
   x   y
0  1  20
1  2  31

dropdf_copy(x)

x
Out[206]: 
   x   y
0  1  20
1  2  31

changecell(x)

x
Out[208]: 
   x   y
0  1  99
1  2  31
```

In the above example dropdf() doesnt modify the original dataframe x while changecell() modifies x. I know if I add the minor change to changecell() it wont change x.

```
def changecell(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['y'][0] = 99
```

I dont think its very elegant to inlcude `df = df.copy()` in every function I write.

***Questions***

1) Under what circumstances does pandas change the original dataframe and when it does not? Can someone give me a clear generalizable rule? I know it may have something to do with mutability Vs immutability but its not clearly explained in stackoverflow.

2) Does numpy behave simillary or its different? What about other python objects?

PS: I have done research in stackoverflow but couldnt find a clear generalizable rule for this problem.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default python does pass by reference. Only if a explicit copy is made in the function like assignment or a copy() function is used the original  object passed is unchanged.

Example with explicit copy :

```
#1. Assignment 
def dropdf_copy1(df):

    df = df.drop('y',axis=1)
#2. copy()
def dropdf_copy2(df):
    df = df.copy() 
    df.drop('y',axis=1,inplace = True)
```

If explicit copy is not done then original object passed is changed.

```
def dropdf_inplace(df):
    df.drop('y',axis=1,inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to deal with pandas. It'a problem of [local/global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) variables on mutable values. in dropdf, you set df as a local variable.

The same with lists:

```
def global_(l):
    l[0]=1

def local_(l):
    l=l+[0]
```

in the second function, it will be the same if  you wrote :

```
def local_(l):
    l2=l+[0]
```

so you don't affect `l`.

Here the [python tutor exemple](http://pythontutor.com/live.html#code=def%20global_%28l%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20l%5B0%5D%3D1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20local_%28l%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20l%3Dl%2B%5B0%5D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Al%3D%5B0%5D%0A%0Aglobal_%28l%29%0A%0Alocal_%28l%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) which shoes what happen.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is the general rule here?