# Insert a column into a Dataframe without modifying the original frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `df_orig` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
exam_data  = {'name': ['X1', 'X2', 'X3'],
        'score': [12.5, 9, 16.5],
        'attempts': [1, 3, 2],
        'qualify': ['yes', 'no', 'yes']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df_orig = pd.DataFrame(exam_data , index=labels)
print("Orginal rows:")
print(df_orig)
df1 = df_orig
color = ['Red','Blue','Orange']
df1['color'] = color
print("\nNew DataFrame after inserting the 'color' column")
print(df1)
print("\nOriginal Dataframe")
print(df_orig)
```

I am trying to insert a new column as `"color"` into the new `DataFrame` `df1`. The above code works very well, but the problem is, when I insert the new column in `df1`, the original dataframe `df_orig` also changes with the new column `"color"`. So, my question is how can I do this insertion without changing the original `DataFrame`.

Comment: You need to use a copy of the dataframe, currently you are editing the same dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does pandas do pass-by-reference Vs pass-by-value when passing dataframe to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003629/when-does-pandas-do-pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value-when-passing-dataframe-to)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid changing the original `DataFrame` use:

```
df1 = df_orig.copy()
```

By default, Python passes by reference. An explicit copy is required to keep unchanged the original object.

Comment: @nahidkhosh, in case this answer was useful, I would appreciate you validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the `copy()`, you can try with DataFrame.assign()

METHOD 4: ADD COLUMNS WITH THE ASSIGN FUNCTION

https://builtin.com/data-science/pandas-add-column